# Age description and hyphenating

Tags: grammar, hyphenation, numbers, attributive-nouns

How would I say a toddler is 2 years and 7 months old correctly? Is this right:

> It is a two-year-seven-month-old toddler.

Or do I need an “and”  between? I personally think hyphenating here looks ridiculous. In formal English, say a report document about child behaviour or whatever, could I write

> It is a two year, seven month old toddler

instead, too?

Comment: By the time a child reaches two and a half years old, I'd say the impersonal pronoun, ‘it’, sounds inappropriately detached.

Comment: @Mari-LouA They're called the "terrible twos" for a reason, no?

Answer (score 2):

I have never actually seen either of those usages; what I normally see is either

> thirty-one-month-old [child]

or, if less precision is needed,

> two-and-a-half-year-old [child]

You could also say

> [S/he] is two years and seven months old

or

> [S/he] is thirty-one months old